# what does this integer mean?

Tags: sql, mysql

hi people i am new at php and wondering what does `int(4)` mean in creating this table. thanks for helping.

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(
name VARCHAR (50),
age INT(4),
email VARCHAR (50)
);
```

Comment: -1: What has this got to do with php? Integer tag is misleading. What database system are you using (Mysql, Mssql etc)? Also please try and pick a better title.

Comment: i use mysql, and i just wondering

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using MySQL, it is the display width of the integer.  You can find this sort of information in [the MySQL user manual:](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html)

> For example, `INT(4)` specifies an `INT` with a display width of four digits.

Answer (score 2):

The code you have posted is no PHP, but a SQL statement for creating a database table called `mytable` with three columns - name, age and email. The statement also has the date types of the different columns, so the database system can know how to store and retrieve them.

Int is a [data type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187594.aspx) in the database - an integer (whole number).

What it means depends on the database you use - in SQL Server the 4 specifies the field precision. However, this will always be the size of an `int` in SQL Server. It can holdvalues between -2,147,483,648 and 2,147,483,647.

If MySQL, it means the display width of the field.

Comment: If the OP is using MySQL then it is not the size in bytes.

Comment: @James McNellis - The OP has not specified DBMS. I have updated my answer to be more specific.

Comment: According to the SQL Server documentation, the (4) specifies precision, not length, so it has effectively the same meaning as in MySQL (though, I haven't used SQL Server extensively to know for sure).

Answer (score 1):

It depends entirely on your RDBMS: there is no standard meaning. Most will simply ignore it, or treat it as a display hint (like MySQL).